# How to randomly choose from arraylist and loops again if the user wants to play again?

Tags: java

I'm stuck on where you need to pick a random quotation from the ArrayList and loop again if the user says "yes".

Should I be using any for-loop or while-loop or something?
Please let me know which direction I should be heading.

Following is what I've done so far:

```
while (userGuess != numToGuess) {
    if (userGuess < numToGuess) {
        System.out.println("too low; try again");
        userGuess = s.nextInt();

    } else if (userGuess > numToGuess) {
        System.out.println("too high; try again");
        userGuess = s.nextInt();

    } else {
        System.out.println("wrong; try again!");
        userGuess = s.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a similar loop around your inner loop to ask if user wants to play again.

Comment: You mean inside the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

imprt this and add the change code as below,

```
public void guessMyNumber()
{
  Random r = new Random();
  numToGuess = r.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String answer;
  do{

     System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1 and 10");
     userGuess = s.nextInt();

     while(userGuess != numToGuess)
     {
         if(userGuess < numToGuess)
         {
             System.out.println("too low; try again");
             userGuess = s.nextInt();
         }
         else if(userGuess > numToGuess){
             System.out.println("too high; try again");
             userGuess = s.nextInt();
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("wrong; try again!");
             userGuess = s.nextInt();
         }
     }
     System.out.println("Congratulations! You've won a quotation.");
     System.out.println("Do you want to continue ?(Yes/No)");
     System.out.println("Quotation is :"+numbersget(r.nextInt(numbers.size())));
     answer=input.next();
  }while((answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) 
}
```

this should do it .

Comment: Oh I see, using do-while loop. We haven't covered that in class yet. But I'll do it any way. How do you randomly choose a quotation from the arraylist?

Comment: It doesn't seem to, what you could do is simply set up another random number and use that as the index for the quote you want to display.

Comment: @user2467271 see my post it might be help you with quotations

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to get the array out of your list as list.toArray().
Then use Math.Random on the size of array to pick the array index randomly and use that to pick a random quotation.

Comment: We haven't done that in class yet, so not sure if I'm allowed to use it! But thanks for suggestion. I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void guessMyNumber()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        String playAgain="Yes";
        while(playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
             numToGuess = r.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
        System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1 and 10");
        userGuess = s.nextInt();

        while(userGuess != numToGuess)
        {
            if(userGuess < numToGuess)
            {
                System.out.println("too low; try again");
                userGuess = s.nextInt();
            }
            else if(userGuess > numToGuess){
                System.out.println("too high; try again");
                userGuess = s.nextInt();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("wrong; try again!");
                userGuess = s.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You've won a quotation.");
        System.out.println("Quotation is :"+numbers.get(r.nextInt(numbers.size())));
        System.out.println("play again? Yes or No?");
        playAgain = s.next();
    }
    }
```

Comment: what is numbersget()? Is that calling the accessor method for quotation from the other class?

Comment: numbers is a arraylist right? so its calling numbers.get(index), index is randomized here. have edited the post(its having a  '.')

Comment: ooops! I feel stupid now. But thanks for help guys. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here?

```
   if(userGuess < numToGuess)
    {
        System.out.println("too low; try again");
        userGuess = s.nextInt();
    }
    else if(userGuess > numToGuess){
        System.out.println("too high; try again");
        userGuess = s.nextInt();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("wrong; try again!");
        userGuess = s.nextInt();
    }
```

If `userGuess` is less than `numToGuess` you say it's "too low", if it is greater you say "too high". If it is equal, you say "wrong; try again". What will the poor user do? :P

For what it's worth... the final else case never occurs (and should be removed) because you won't get into the while loop if `userGuess == numToGuess`.

Comment: There's a range 1-10 from where user can guess the number from. If he's entering below 1, I say "too low". If it's more than 10, I say "too high". And if it's within the range but the number guessed is not right, I say "wrong". Am I not doing it right? Please sugest if I'm going wrong.

Comment: @user2467271 is there ever a case when your control flow reaches the last `else` block?

Comment: I'm not sure what control flow means but it looks okay in BlueJ in terms of scope. I mean it's color coded same for the last else block as the previous if-else statements. Sorry this is my first programming course , so not very good with technical vocabulary

Comment: That's fine @user2467271, you'll get to know everything in time. All the best. Cheers.